# Casting YouTube video to Chromecast

Tags: android, youtube, google-cast, chromecast

Is there any way to connect to the "YouTube" app on the public Chromecast SDK for Android?

Simply setting the app id to "YouTube" used to work in the developer preview, but now it says that it is an invalid app id.

This is my previous question regarding the matter with the preview SDK: [Open Chromecast YouTube video from my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115563/open-chromecast-youtube-video-from-my-android-app)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the current YT app and new version of Cast SDK, you cannot do that as you used to be able to.

Comment: Any chance we can get this feature back? This would be a huge plus for my app in particular. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not up to the Cast SDK alone to do that; it is up to the individual apps as well. For example, SDK will not provide an easy way for you to start, say, Hulu+ and play a movie there since, most likely, Hulu+ folks won't be happy with that and they would want you to use their own app. Engage with the YouTube folks (or any other app that you want to launch from within your app) and see if they would provide a way for you to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast youtube to google home (tested with google mini). So this is a workaround. Click on Cast on the youtube video. Then on the popup switch source from the youtube to the Caste Tab. Whoilaaa, on the list you will see you home speaker/s.

P.S. If anybody from Google read this post, please don't kill this feature :-)

[image]