# Android youtube sdk integration with Google chromecast

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast

Is it possible to cast a video from YouTube player SDK form android?

Please let me know steps to do it.

Comment: we're not a free research service, read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link for you tube integration

[Open Chromecast youtube video from android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450163/open-chromecast-youtube-video-from-android-application)

https://github.com/jlmcdonald/yt-chromecast-demo

Comment: Avoid link only answers

Comment: So u mean parsing the url from youtube videoId and sending to chromecast receiver?

Comment: you can try with this because currently no  API or procedure available for the same that is why i have sent this demo link. In this also a way to do . you can say it is also a work around

Comment: FYI github link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I endup creating an webapp with iframe for chromecast device

And for android app, sending message like "load,play,pause" by alerting code in https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android